# Some parameters are missing when I send the body with fetch to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I want to make a fetch request with JS but when I add last two parameters at the end of the body (`vs` and `deviceName`), these two do not reach the API:

```
vs: Constants.expoConfig.version,
deviceName: Device.modelName,
```

All the  other parameters are sending right, but I don't know what is the problem, because I am sure my API side is correct, but this two are not sending at all, and I am sure they have the correct value, they are not null or empty:

```
  var _body = JSON.stringify({
          SignatureType: 0,
          ContractNo: kNo,
          Kvkk: isSelected,
          ElectronicCommercialMessagePermission: isSelected02,
          RentalConditions: isSelected03,
          DocumentId: dId,
          LanguageId: LanguageId,
          vs: Constants.expoConfig.version,
          deviceName: Device.modelName,
        });
  await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
          body: _body,
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.text();
          })
          .then(async (json) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setIsDocumentLoading(false);
          });
```

I tried to change headers, CORS modes, or JSON structure, but it didn't work.